# The arrow function does not work when I put it inside the object, the result after call is NaN

Tags: javascript

```
var mySelf = {
  name: "dina",
  job: "Programmer",
  yearOfBirth: 1993,
  age: () => 2019 - this.yearOfBirth
};

let result = mySelf.age();

console.log(result);
```

the result is `NaN`

please help me what actually happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arrow function inherit the enclosing context (that is `Window` in this case) rather then the object context, use a plain function instead.

```js
var mySelf = {
  name: "dina",
  job: "Programmer",
  yearOfBirth: 1993,
  age: function() { return 2019 - this.yearOfBirth }
};
    
let result = mySelf.age();
    
console.log(result);
```

To show that an arrow function receives a lexical `this` -

```js
const o =
  { func: () => this === window }
  
console.log(o.func()) // true
```

Comment: thanks, it works ! :D

Answer (score 3):

If use the name `mySelf` instead of `this`(because it will not reference the object in this case) to reference your object it seems to work fine.

```js
var mySelf = {
  name: "dina",
  job: "Programmer",
  yearOfBirth: 1993,
  age: () => 2019 - mySelf.yearOfBirth
};

let result = mySelf.age();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if you reassign the variable?

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean ?

Comment: `otherVar = mySelf; mySelf = 3; let result = otherVar.age();`

Comment: More practically, suppose you have an array full of these objects, rather than having them in specific variables, and want to call `personArray[i].age()`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the property of the arrow function is that the context used in the function is the upper context. So `this.yearOfBirth` refer to a context when `yearOfBirth` do not exist (the document context).

---

Also do not use `2019` statically. `2020` is closer than you think.

---

```js
const mySelf = {
  name: 'dina',
  job: 'Programmer',
  yearOfBirth: 1993,

  age: () => Number(new Date().getFullYear()) - this.yearOfBirth,
};

const result = mySelf.age();

console.log(result);
```

---

To make it work you can use a regular function.

```js
const mySelf = {
  name: 'dina',
  job: 'Programmer',
  yearOfBirth: 1993,

  age: function() { 
     return Number(new Date().getFullYear()) - this.yearOfBirth;
  },
};

const result = mySelf.age();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not captured in this context with an arrow function. That's actually the main difference with the classic `function` way of defining functions.

This means that the `this` does refer to the global object (`window`in a browser) when you actually execute it in your example.

Since there is no global `yearOfBirth` binding, `this.yearOfBirth` will return `undefined`, and any math performed with `undefined` gives `NaN`.

---

A simple solution would be to use a function instead `function() {return 2019 - this.yearOfBirth}`. (see executable examples in other answers)

You can also use a more "object oriented" approach by using the ES2015 `class` keyword, in this case the arrow function will behave as you expected.

```js
class Person {
  name = "dina";
  job = "Programmer";
  yearOfBirth = 1993;
  age = () => 2019 - this.yearOfBirth;
}

let mySelf = new Person

console.log(mySelf.age());
```